# RunTime Complexity of my Power method

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, pow

This is my implementation of the power method.

1. If the power is an even number, I square the base, and divide the
   power by 2.
2. If the power is an odd number, I run the method recursively, with
   the power reduced by 1, so as to get an even number, and multiply
   the result by base, to account for the power reduced by one.
3. The base case is reached when the power is 1, and the result is 0.

My question is, what is the time complexity of this method? Since, we're dividing the power by 2, on every iteration, is it logn to the base 2 ?

```
      double myPow(double base, int pow) {
      if(pow == 0)
          return 1;

      if(pow < 0)
          return 1/base * 1/myPow(base, (pow*-1)-1);

      if(pow %2 == 1)
          return base * myPow(base, pow-1);
      else
          return myPow(base*base, pow/2);
    }
```

Comment: yes, you are correct

Answer (score 3):

Yes, complexity is logarithmic. Your method is essentially [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Number of squarings is equal to the number of zeros in binary expansion of pow, and number of multiplications is equal to the number of ones in binary expansion of pow, so overall number of operations is about the number of significant bits of pow, `log2(pow)`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your idea that this power method is O(log n). Note that I haven't included the base of this log (in this case base 2), this is because [all logs differ by a constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/clarify-why-all-logarithms-differ-by-a-constant).

MBo gives a brief explanation above as to why this is the case, but I'd like to go into a bit more detail as to why this is the case.

First of all, we need to decide what the runtime of this method depends on. Notice that no matter what the base is, if the power is the same, the runtime will be the same (give or take inconsequential randomness). However, when the power changes, the runtime will change, based on, as MBo stated, the number of significant bits.

But what does this mean? Well, consider these two cases (read these assignments in binary, I'm using psuedocode here):

```
case 1:
pow = 1000

case 2:
pow = 1111
```

You'll notice that these two cases are the best and worst case scenario for a given number of bits. The first allows us to neatly divide by 2 until we hit the base case, that the other makes us subtract 1 before dividing by two, leading to twice the number of operations as the first.

As big O is about worst case time complexity, let's look at the worst case in more depth (considering the first neatly leads us to log n time). We have to perform the same number of divisions as the best case, but each one is prepended by a subtraction. This means that we end up with 2*log n time. However, as I stated above, big O doesn't care about constants, so we end up with O(log n) time asymptotically. This means that the number of significant bits (or the number of bits the number has) bounds the number of operations that need to be performed (bits <= ops <= 2*bits).

I hope this could shed some more light on the question you had. If you don't get anything else out of this, please remember that big O doesn't care about constants, wherever they may lie.